# the bitcoin wallet spendable amount is not updating

Tags: wallet, watch-only

the spendable amount is not updating to the watch only amount. this is now going on 3 weeks or longer. I am using bitcoin ver 0.12.1

any ideas??

Comment: looks like almost all of my transactions are labeled as (watch only).

Comment: Did you specifically add these addresses as watch-only? If all your transactions are labeled as watch-only that sounds like you don't have the private keys in your wallet which would explain why your spendable amount is not updating.

Comment: I upgraded computers and had to reload bitcoin. I did add addresses manually. is there a way that I can find my private key to remove the "watch only"??

Answer (score 1):

**Definition of Watch-only Adress:**

An address or pubkey script stored in the wallet without the corresponding private key, allowing the wallet to watch for outputs but not spend them.

**So you should find your private keys in order to spend these adresses**

Answer (score 0):

I had to open up the old wallet, wait for the wallet to sync and then I transferred all the coins out from the old wallet to the new wallet.

Comment: You should probably edit this to say that this is a workaround.  By transferring the bitcoin from one wallet to another, you didn't import the private keys, you simply spent the bitcoin to yourself.